# Get psyco speedup on x64 architecture?

Tags: python, psyco

Is there a way to get the same sort of speedup on x64 architecture as you can get from psyco on 32 bit processors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately, Psyco [only runs on 32-bit x86 right now](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/introduction.html).

Comment: Forgive my editing your answer, I tried to make it more accurate.