# Installed PyPy + NumPy, but I experienced no improvement in performance. Is this normal?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pypy

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

CPU: i7

1. I Installed PyPy+Numpy:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install pypy pypy-dev
   pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git
   ```
2. Ran following code with `python` and `pypy`:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import time

   start = time.clock()

   for i in range(5):
       vv = np.random.rand(9000000).astype(np.float32)
       m = np.mean(vv)

   print 'Done in %.3f s %s ' % (time.clock()-start,m)
   ```

   And got the following timings:

   ```
   $python testSpeed_.py
   Done in 1.908 s 0.499997

   $pypy testSpeed_.py
   Done in 4.599 s 0.499952167273
   ```

i.e. no performance improvement. Should I have gotten a performance boost?

Comment: I don't see why pypy would help you with this kind of stuff - numpy is really a wrapper for C functions.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18946662/1461210

Comment: you will see improvements with PyPy if you try to do anything in Python code (e.g. iterate over numpy arrays), however vectorized operations will be at best as fast (but indeed sometimes even slower), since then you're just calling optimized C and there is not that much to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation of PyPy [here](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#should-i-install-numpy-or-numpypy), `numpy` under `PyPy` is slow:

> At the moment of writing (October 2017) the main drawback of numpy is that cpyext is infamously slow