# Does PyPy support gmpy2?

Tags: python, pypy, python-cffi, gmpy

It seems from the discussions [issue #60](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmpy/issues/60) and [issue #40](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmpy/issues/40) that PyPy couldn't build gmpy before. All I intend to use currently is the probable prime `is_prime` code which is conveniently in gmpy2. I get the impression that the more calls to gmpy2 means less efficiency for PyPy. Is using gmpy2  possible currently, or do I have to use something like GMPY_CFFI?

The error I get when using pip in PyPy is `cannot open include file 'mpir.h'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [GMPY_CFFI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy_cffi/0.1). `gmpy` and `gmpy2` rely on too many internal details of CPython to be ported to PyPy.

Note: I maintain `gmpy2`.